# Flask-migrate and changing column type

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, flask, alembic

I am trying to learn some Flask and I am using Flask-Migrate 1.6.0

So I made a model which looks like this

```py
class Download(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "downloads"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    size = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    season = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    download_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)

    show_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey("shows.id"))

    def __init__(self,filename,size,location,timestamp,season):
        self.filename = filename
        self.size = size
        self.location = location
        self.download_timestamp = timestamp
        self.season = season

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<File {}'.format(self.filename)
```

I have then changed it to the exact same thing except for this line :

```py
size = db.Column(db.BigInteger, nullable=False)
```

When I run my

```sh
manager.py db migrate
```

command it doesn't detect the change in the column type. And I have read up on it and I know it should pick it up when I change my env.py and add the compare_type=True variable. But I did this to no avail, the method looks like this right now

```py
def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """

    # this callback is used to prevent an auto-migration from being generated
    # when there are no changes to the schema
    # reference: http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html
    def process_revision_directives(context, revision, directives):
        if getattr(config.cmd_opts, 'autogenerate', False):
            script = directives[0]
            if script.upgrade_ops.is_empty():
                directives[:] = []
                logger.info('No changes in schema detected.')

    engine = engine_from_config(config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
                                prefix='sqlalchemy.',
                                poolclass=pool.NullPool)

    connection = engine.connect()
    context.configure(connection=connection,
                      target_metadata=target_metadata,
                      compare_type=True,
                      process_revision_directives=process_revision_directives,
                      **current_app.extensions['migrate'].configure_args)

    try:
        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Ok so my questions are:

Did I do something wrong in changing the env.py file?

If I didn't and it still doesn't pick up on it how do I exactly manually make the next migration revision? Because the revisions in my migrate folder have names like below and stuff in it like this

```py
# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '7e9f264b0f'
down_revision = '2e59d536f50'
```

I guess I could just copy one, make up a name .. but would the next one that is picked up by flask migrate recognize it? So yeah.. what is the correct way of handling it without too much iffy hacking?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Update:**

As expected, this answer is now out of date, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52181159/428907 for a real fix!

**Original Answer:**

Alembic does not recognize things like column type changes when auto-generating revisions by default. When making these more granular changes, you will need to hand-modify the migration to include these changes

e.g., in your migration file

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
def upgrade():
    # ...
    op.alter_column('downloads', 'size', existing_type=sa.Integer(), type_=sa.BigInteger())
def downgrade():
    # ...
    op.alter_column('downloads', 'size', existing_type=sa.BigInteger(), type_=sa.Integer())
```

For details on the operations, see [the operation reference](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html)

You can turn on detection of type changes by modifying your env.py and alembic.ini, as seen [here](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/autogenerate.html#what-does-autogenerate-detect-and-what-does-it-not-detect)

Comment: The provided links do not work... operation reference can be found here: http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html

Comment: This is useful if you have to write your own migrations, but that is not necessary, better to change the default behavior and initialize alembic to detect those migrations.  The right answer is below - change the default behavior to detect those type of changes.

Comment: This link helped select the exact code to modify the env.py file for alembic migrations: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/24

Answer (score 112):

Just need to add `compare_type=True` in the Migrate constructor

```
from flask_migrate import Migrate
migrate = Migrate(compare_type=True)

app = Flask(__name__)
migrate.init_app(app)
```

Comment: This is the Correct answer.

Comment: Correct and clean answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works perfectly.

Comment: Alembic users, see here for the equivalent: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html#comparing-types

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. So confusing to have the other one as accepted.

Comment: Why is this not the default ?  After all its a DB change which migrate should catch.

Answer (score 9):

By default, Flask-migrate doesn't track the changes when type of column is changed. One of many ways to achieve this is to set

> compare_type=True

Under **env.py**. e.g. -

```
context.configure(connection=connection,
                      target_metadata=target_metadata,
                      process_revision_directives=process_revision_directives,
                      compare_type=True,
                      **current_app.extensions['migrate'].configure_args)
```

Comment: It's possible I'm doing something incorrectly, but this approach doesn't seem to work using Flask-Migrate 2.5.2.

Answer (score 3):

Tha `flask-migrate` didn't detect the **`Column`** changes most of the time. If you delete the `size` field then `flask-migrate` will detect the change. Then run

`manager.py db migrate`

Then add `size` filed

`size = db.Column(db.BigInteger, nullable=False)` 
and migrate.

Comment: Well ok, but that would add a lot of hassle when it comes to preserving the data right?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a script for an automated way to add the compare_type=true in Flask, feel free to used and improve it.

```
make dbinit
sudo sed -i '75i\                      compare_type=True,' env.py
make dbmigrate
make dbupgadre
```

Cheers,